# Why am I missing a parameter when I have entered it into the form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting this error for a simple form:

[image]

I made a form in my new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @party do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>

   <%= f.submit "Save" %>
 <% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class PartiesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @party = Party.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @party = Party.new
  end

  def create
    @party = Party.new(params.require(:title))
    if @party.save
      flash[:notice] = "Party was saved"
      redirect_to @party
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why the error occurs if I have a title field in my form, and it is listed as one of my params even in my error screen.

[image]

Comment: it should be `params.require(:party).permit(:title)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do NOT use screen captures to show us errors or code. They're difficult to read, and are not searchable, making it more difficult for people who want to find the answer to a similar question. Instead, copy/paste the information into your question, and format it for readability. That will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your params is a hash (or rather extended version of Hash), which is in format:

```
{
  'party' => {
    'title' => 'your value'
  }
}
```

Now when you call `require(:key)` on such a "hash", it will check whether it contains such a key (and the value is not blank). However, your `params` hash only contain single key `'party'`, hence you are getting an error. `require` method returns a value corresponding to required key, so you can then call `permit` method which will mark given key as acceptable and safe.

So finally your call should be:

```
params.require(:party).permit(:title)
```

NOTE: `params` is not really a hash, it is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` - this is why it doesn't care whether you use symbol or string to specify the key.

As noted in other answers, it is the best practice to wrap those expression within a private method, as it is usually common for create and update action.

Answer (score 0):

Your `party_params` action in `PartiesController` need to be like this:

```
def party_params
  params.require(:party).permit(:title)
end
```

Then change your `create` action into this:

```
def create
    @party = Party.new(party_params)
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

on your `create`

```
def create
  @party = Party.new params.require(:party).permit(:title)
end
```

also, you can put the params.require... on a private method so

```
private
def party_params
  params.require(:party).permit(:title)
end
```

so now, you can use party params wherever you may need them. ex:

```
@party = Party.new party_params
or
@party.update party_params
```